# Checking the sum of 2 random numbers in PHP before page is refreshed

Tags: php, random

I am developing a site in MODX Revo.  I have a form on the site, with a section that generates 2 random numbers between 1 - 5, and a box that asks the user to enter the sum of the 2 numbers.

Thats all fine, but when I'm checking to see if what they entered is equal to the two random numbers, the two randoms have already changed (when the page is refreshed with Submit button), so I can't check.

I generate the 2 randoms, and check their value against the user input like this in a snippet

```
$test = $_POST['test']; // result of user input
$random1 = mt_rand(1,5);
$random2 = mt_rand(1,5);
$maths_result = $random1+$random2;
if($test != $maths_result)
        {
            // display error message here
        }
```

So how can I check the sum of the 2 randoms before the page is refreshed.  Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is the goal to make user (bindly) guess the die before it's cast ..?

Answer (score 0):

Put the sum of the random numbers in a session variable. Then you have access to it on the next page load.

Here's a basic example:

```
<?php 
session_start();

if ('POST' !== $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
  $random1 = mt_rand(1,5);
  $random2 = mt_rand(1,5);
  $_SESSION['math_result'] = $random1+$random2;
}
else {
  $test = (int) $_POST['test'];
  if ($test !== $_SESSION['math_result']) {
    // fail
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes this seems obvious, but I'm doing everything on the same page, so would I do the same thing?

Comment: Yes, this is designed to work on one page. It checks to see if the page is posted or not. If not, it generates the number to be guessed. If so, it compares the submitted value to the saved value and reports if there is an error.

Comment: Thank you John.  Been playing around with this today and got it working.

Comment: May have spoken to soon on this.  I can get it to check if the number the user inputs is the same value as the 2 random numbers, but this is part of a larger form with validation on it.  If they get another aspect of the form wrong, the 2 random numbers disappear because they only get generated if the form has not posted back yet.  I can't get the 2 random numbers to stay on the form if gets posted back with errors.  Any other ideas would be great.  Thank you

Comment: Save them in the session, too. Then they'll stay available across page loads.